# jQuery write ajax html response

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I have the following jQuery and the file set-rank.php just updates a database and in the file it also writes the new data that I want to overwrite the #data section. my console log html response shows what I need it to but I can't get this to jquery to actually write my html response to my page.

**JQUERY**

```
$('input.ranking').keyup(function(e) {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var catID = $('input[name=catid]').val();
    var substr = thisClass.split('-');
    var pdID = substr[1];
    var pdRank = $(this).val();
    qString = 'pdID='+pdID+'&pdRank='+pdRank+'&catID='+catID;
    //console.log(qString);
        $.post('/assets/inc/set-rank.php', qString, function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            $('#data').html(data);
        }, "json");
});
```

thanks in advance

Edit the console .log shows the following image. It wont write this html into my page
[image]

Comment: i need the data from the set-rank.php to overwrite whats inside #data so append would not do this

Comment: What does console.log($('#data').length) show?

Comment: Outside of the .post it shows 1 - inside it shows nothing

Comment: Does #data have a container? Can you get at that container from inside the post callback? Does console.log($('body').length) print 1 (inside the post callback)?

Comment: .length only prints 1 outside of post callback

Comment: Even for console.log($('body').length)?

Comment: that only works outside of post

Comment: What if you do var dataDiv = $('#data'); $.post(..., function(data) { dataDiv.html(data) }); ?

Comment: Nope, even if I console.log("Hello"); inside the post it doesn't show it on the console.log();

Comment: Are you sure the POST is succeeding? If it doesn't, that callback isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last argument of `$.post` aka the `json` string. Since from what I see on your screenshot, the server returns HTML and not JSON data, so that causes it to fail.

Also: Instead of creating the string yourself you can pass an object into jquery's `data` parameter as in `{rank: pdRank, catId: id}`

Comment: I need it to pass html not json though

Comment: Did you remove the 'json' argument from the $.post call? Did it work?

Comment: I am kicking myself right now at how stupid i was for leaving that json in the end! Thanks @Aldo